# Assign beautifulsoup text to string list

Tags: python, string, list, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a string list (or array) out of text retrieved from a websites html and then print a given index. I am using the `find_all` function from beautiful soup to retrieve the text. Is there a way to access the objects directly from the beautifulsoup object? Or do I need to create a string list from the object? if so how come my current code is not working?

My attempt:

```
    html = urlopen("http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/" + word + "?s=t")
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "lxml")
    for synonym in bsObj.find_all("span", class_="text"):
        synlist = synlist.append(synonym.text)
except:
    print(word)
print(synlist[2])
```

The error I am getting is:

> NameError: name 'synlist' is not defined

Comment: define a `synlist`  array first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just use:

```
try:
    html = urlopen("http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/" + word + "?s=t")
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "lxml")
    synlist = bsObj.find_all("span", class_="text")

except:
    print(word)

print(synlist[2].text)
```

it makes an array by itself, why make another?

EDIT: btw i dont know what word is, im assuming it exists somewhere else. also python tab spacing was wrong, and my ocd you know?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `synlist` before `try` like this
    `synlist`=[]